# Digital Ocean HTML Files Uploaded Not Working

Tags: html, digital-ocean

I have uploaded some html files to my Digital Ocean droplet, on directory `/var/www/html`, but apparently I still can't connect to `http://vps-ip-address`, how can I make those files work on default http port when simply typing `http://vps-ip-address`? I know I'm missing something out and it's probably a newbie mistake, so if someone could explain to me how it can be done, I would be grateful.

Comment: Did you install any web server (apache or nginx) and configure it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I think I have installed nginx. I'm running node and mongodb in my vps, how can I see if I have nginx installed?

Comment: Do you have registered domain that points to your www/html folder?

Comment: No, right now I don't have a registered domain, just the vps's ip address.

Comment: Check process list for process nginx. Also check /etc/nginx/ for files.

Comment: Ok I have nginx installed, how can I configure it to open my index.html inside /var/www/html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default on Ubuntu, the document root for Nginx is located at `/usr/share/nginx/html` In order to serve content from `/var/www/html` you will need to edit your Nginx configuration. The default configuration file is `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Find the line:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

and change it to:

```
root /var/www/html;
```

Then restart Nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`